# how to set DPI using Golang?

Tags: image, go, jfif

Golang image package is very handy to some extent but lack the support to set DPI of an image. I checked the file header of generated file, `FF D8 FF DB` which looks like jpeg raw. AFAIK, raw doesn't come with DPI like what jfif has. So here's my question, how to set DPI of the generated image? Or how to convert a raw to jfif, from which I know I can edit a specific bit of the file to set DPI? Previously I embedded an AdvancedBatchConverter executable in my app and used `exec.Command(fmt.Sprintf("%s/AdvancedBatchConverter/abc.exe", cwd), outputFile, "/jfif", fmt.Sprintf("/convert=%s", jfifFileName))`
 to do the trick, but really, disgusted by it every time I looked at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the exif values `XResolution` and `YResolution`

My understanding is the native jpeg encoder doesn't have any options for exif data.

https://github.com/dsoprea/go-exif will let you modify the exif data.

Additionally I believe if you first write the jpeg to a bytes.Buffer or similar and then append the exif you can do the entire thing in memory without flushing to disk first.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’ll try your approach when I can spare some time, but the idea sounds very promising. BTW the library doesn’t do what the name shows. It can only parse exif info when I checked a couple days ago. Will add more comment when I got more updates.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I didn't have time to verify until this week. For the record, go-exif isn't a feasible package to **add** exif information. https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html is a good article, outlined what bytes should be set to write a new exif into file.

Answer (score 1):

github.com/dsoprea/go-exif/v2 can reader and write exif data.
with other package github.com/dsoprea/go-jpeg-image-structure
here is code example . for write DPI(XResolution, YResolution) to Image.

```
import( 
    exif2 "github.com/dsoprea/go-exif/v2"
    exifcommon "github.com/dsoprea/go-exif/v2/common"
    jpegstructure "github.com/dsoprea/go-jpeg-image-structure"
)
func SetExifData(filepath string) error {
jmp := jpegstructure.NewJpegMediaParser()

intfc, err := jmp.ParseFile(filepath)
log.PanicIf(err)

sl := intfc.(*jpegstructure.SegmentList)

// Make sure we don't start out with EXIF data.
wasDropped, err := sl.DropExif()
log.PanicIf(err)

if wasDropped != true {
    fmt.Printf("Expected the EXIF segment to be dropped, but it wasn't.")
}

im := exif2.NewIfdMapping()

err = exif2.LoadStandardIfds(im)
log.PanicIf(err)

ti := exif2.NewTagIndex()
rootIb := exif2.NewIfdBuilder(im, ti, exifcommon.IfdPathStandard, exifcommon.EncodeDefaultByteOrder)

err = rootIb.AddStandardWithName("XResolution", []exifcommon.Rational{{Numerator: uint32(96), Denominator: uint32(1)}})
log.PanicIf(err)

err = rootIb.AddStandardWithName("YResolution", []exifcommon.Rational{{Numerator: uint32(96), Denominator: uint32(1)}})
log.PanicIf(err)

err = sl.SetExif(rootIb)
log.PanicIf(err)

b := new(bytes.Buffer)

err = sl.Write(b)
log.PanicIf(err)

if err := ioutil.WriteFile(filepath, b.Bytes(), 0644); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("write file err: %v", err)
}
return nil
}
```